# How to Sort the first dimension of a 2D Array Swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

Im trying to sort the columns of a CSV file,the contents of the CSV is provided in  string

```
Beth,Charles,Danielle,Adam,Eric\n
17945,10091,10088,3907,10132\n
2,12,13,48,11
```

Converted String to 2D Array

```
[["Beth", "Charles", "Danielle", "Adam", "Eric"], ["17945", "10091", "10088", "3907", 
"10132"], ["2", "12", "13", "48", "11"]]
```

How can i sort the only the first dimension of the 2D array or the Names in the 2D Array and still keep the mappings of the other dimension, i don't know how to explain this properly, but i hope the details below will help you understand what i want to achieve.

```
Adam,Beth,Charles,Danielle,Eric\n
3907,17945,10091,10088,10132\n
48,2,12,13,11
```

I want to achieve this with the names sorted and the other values in the other arrays mapping to the names like below,

```
[["Adam", "Beth", "Charles", "Danielle", "Eric"], ["3907", "17945", "10091", "10088", 
"10132"], ["48", "2", "12", "13", "11"]]
```

Using this approach is not working but sorts the whole array

```
let sortedArray  = 2dArray.sorted(by: {($0[0] as! String) < ($1[0] as! String) })
[["3907", "17945", "10091", "10088", "10132"], ["48", "2", "12", "13", "11"], ["Adam", "Beth", "Charles", "Danielle", "Eric"]]
```

Below if the full code

```
var stringCSV = 
"Beth,Charles,Danielle,Adam,Eric\n17945
,10091,10088,3907,10132\n2,12,13,48,11";

var csvFormatted = [[String]]()

stringCSV.enumerateLines { line , _ in
var res = line.split(separator: ",",omittingEmptySubsequences: 
false).map{ String($0) }
for i in 0 ..< res.count {
    res[i] = res[i]
  }
    csvFormatted.append(res)
  
   }

   print(csvFormatted)
   let sortedArray  = csvFormatted.sorted(by: {($0[0] as! String) 
   <  ($1[0] as! String) })
   print(sortedArray)
```

Comment: I would start by converting to an array of structs, each with three properties, rather than using a 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "associated" arrays always ends up being messy.

I would start by creating a struct to represent each object (You haven't said what the numbers are, so I have picked a couple of property names.  I have also kept `String` as their type, but converting to `Int` is possibly better, depending on what the data actually represents).

```
struct Person {
   let name: String
   let id: String
   let age: String
}
```

Now you can combine the arrays and use that to build an array of these structs.  Then you can sort by the `name` property.

```
    let properties = zip(sourceArray[1],sourceArray[2])
    let namesAndProperties = zip(sourceArray[0],properties)
 
    let structArray = namesAndProperties.map { (name,properties) in 
        return Person(name: name, id: properties.0, age: properties.1)
    }

    let sortedArray = structArray.sorted {
        return $0.name < $1.name
    }
```

Comment: assuming the the object in the string or array are unlimited, how am i going to use a struct to solve it ?

Comment: What do you mean unlimited?  `sortedArray` is an Array of `Person` instances.  If there are more than three properties (lines) in your input file then you should explain that.   Do you truly not know how many properties each item has or is there just a large number?  Either way, you could create a struct with a name and a string array.  Put the name in the `name` property and add all of the other elements for that person to the array.

Comment: Yes please lets assume there will be more than 3 properties , but i can use the solution you provided as a starting point to understand what needs to be done.